# UIWebView not scrolling in a UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I have setup 4 view controllers each containing a `UIWebView` and set these up as the Tabs for a `UITabBarController`.

The content loads fine, and the buttons are clickable, however the content of the `UIWebViews` refuses to scroll. `UIWebView` has an inbuilt `UIScrollView` to handle it's own scrolling, so it should just scroll right?

My initialisation code in the main file is:

```
tabBarController = [[MainTabBarController alloc] init];
[tabBarController.view setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, dev_portrait.size.width, 44)];
[tabBarController setDelegate:self];

UIImage* anImage = [UIImage imageNamed:@"53-house.png"];
UITabBarItem* theItem = [[UITabBarItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Home" image:anImage tag:0];
WebViewController *vc1 = [[WebViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"WebController" bundle:nil];
[vc1 setup];
[vc1 setTabBarItem:theItem];

/// ... same for the other 3 WebViewControllers

NSArray* controllers = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4, aNavigationController, nil];
tabBarController.viewControllers = controllers;
//self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
self.window.rootViewController = tabBarController;
```

When a tab is touched, it fires a function in the view controller which loads the URL:

```
- (void)handleURL:(NSString *)url {
    NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];
    NSLog(@"Handling URL: %@", request);
    [webpage loadRequest:request];
    lastURL = url;
    [self startLoaderIndicator];
}
```

Comment: Can you aim your web view at google.com, or someplace big that rules out buggy html?  Another thing to try is manually setting the contentSize to be larger than the bounds.  You shouldn't need to do this, but it will give another clue that maybe its confusing web content.

Comment: You are correct in that the UIWebView should handle its own scrolling. Not going to post an answer because I don't know exactly what to do without having the project in front of me, but things I would check would be if you are implementing UIWebViewDelegate in your view controller and then setting the UIWebView's delegate as self in the view controller.  Although like I said, not 100% sure this will change anything.

Comment: Oh wow, I just tried setting the URL to be a normal webpage with loads of content, and it works! So it must be a problem with the HTML. Omigod, thanks so much!